# Error redirecting prometheus call with nginx

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, docker-compose, prometheus

Why am I getting 404 error after authenticating to the call `http://<ip-external>:80`?

I would like when the call was made, he authenticated with username and password, and it was returned after the page of prometheus

docker.compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: meta_prometheus
    user: '0'
    volumes:
      - /etc/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - /prometheus/data:/prometheus/data
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/data'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    network_mode: host
```

nginx.conf

```
pid        /etc/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;

http {
  server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    location / { 
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/;

      auth_basic "Prometheus";
      auth_basic_user_file ".htpasswd";
    }
  }
}
events {
}
```

returned

[image]

Ref: https://www.robustperception.io/adding-basic-auth-to-prometheus-with-nginx

Nginx version: 1.9

OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9

Comment: could you try to replace "listen 0.0.0.0:80" to "listen 80", restart nginx and try it again?

Comment: I updated, I still have the same problem, does this have anything to do with an external firewall rule?

Comment: Port 80 connects, and 3000 is localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I spent a lot of time to understand how to do everything, below is the complete process to install prometheus with authentication and HTTPS

#### Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    user: '0'
    volumes:
      - /etc/prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - /prometheus/data:/prometheus/data
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus/data'
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    network_mode: host
```

#### Docker command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

#### User

```
htpasswd /docker/htpasswd/prometheus username-here
```

#### Nginx

```
2. yum install mod_ssl

3. yum install openssl

4. openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048

5. openssl req -new -key ca.key -out ca.csr

6. openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in ca.csr -signkey ca.key -out ca.crt

7. cp ca.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs

9. cp ca.key /etc/pki/tls/private/

10. cp ca.csr /etc/pki/tls/private

11. yum install gcc-c++ pcre-dev pcre-devel zlib-devel

12. cd /tmp/;wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.9.9.tar.gz

13. tar zxf nginx-1.9.9.tar.gz

14. cd /tmp/;wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz

15. tar zxf openssl-1.0.1t.tar.gz

16. mv /tmp/openssl-1.0.1t/ /etc/openssl-1.0

17. useradd --no-create-home --shell /bin/false nginx
```

---

```
18. cd nginx-1.9.9

Execute the command below
```

---

```
./configure --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--user=nginx \
--group=nginx \
--with-openssl=/etc/openssl-1.0 \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid
```

---

```
19. make -j2

20. make install
```

---

```
21. vim /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service
```

---

```
[Unit]
Description=The NGINX HTTP and reverse proxy server
After=syslog.target network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t
ExecStart=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx
ExecReload=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s QUIT $MAINPID
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

---

```
22. vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

---

```
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

http {
  server {

    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/ca.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    location / {

      resolver 127.0.0.1 valid=30s;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/;
      auth_basic "Protected by sidecar proxy!";
      auth_basic_user_file /docker/htpasswd/prometheus;

    }
  }
}
events {
}
```

---

```
23. systemctl daemon-reload

24. systemctl enable nginx

25. systemctl start nginx

26. systemctl status nginx
```